# typescript member variable class type changing

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm wrapping jquery's datepicker for use in angular2 and am running into a situation where the class of a member variable is changing somehow. For reference, I'm a beginner here.

First, here is the code (based on the example from http://www.radzen.com/blog/jquery-plugins-and-angular/
):

```
import { forwardRef, ViewChild, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, Component} from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

import * as $ from "jquery";
import 'jqueryui';

const DATE_PICKER_VALUE_ACCESSOR = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => DatePickerComponent),
    multi: true
};

@Component({
    selector: 'qnet-datepicker',
    template: `<input #input type="text">`,
    providers: [DATE_PICKER_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class DatePickerComponent implements AfterViewInit, ControlValueAccessor, OnDestroy {
    private onTouched = () => {};
    private onChange: (date: Date) => void = () => {};

    @Input() date: Date;
    @Input() options: any = {};
    @Output() dateChange = new EventEmitter();

    @ViewChild('input') input: ElementRef;

    constructor() {
        this.date = new Date();
    }

    writeValue(date: Date) {
        if(!date) {
            return;
        }
        this.date = date;
        $(this.input.nativeElement).datepicker('setDate', this.date)
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any) {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
        this.onTouched = fn;
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        $(this.input.nativeElement).datepicker(Object.assign({}, this.options, {
            onSelect: (dateStr: string) => {
//              this.date = $(this.input.nativeElement).datepicker('getDate');
//              this.onChange(this.date);
                this.onTouched();
                this.dateChange.next(this.date);
            }
        }))
console.log('date is ' + this.date)
        $(this.input.nativeElement).datepicker('setDate', this.date)
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        $(this.input.nativeElement).datepicker('destroy');
    }
}
```

In the constructor the type of this.date is 'Date' but by time I get to ngAfterViewInit the type has somehow changed to 'DatePickerComponent'. How can this happen?

*edit*

Additional info: the html using the datepicker was something like

```
<qnet-datepicker #startDate [date]="startDate" (dateChange)="updateStart(startDate.date, startTime.value)"></qnet-datepicker>
```

As ahmed describes in his answer, this ended up accidentally binding the member variable to the element instead of the date. Part of my confusion was relying on typescript being strongly typed, but hookups between html and logic is done via javascript so no longer has the strongly type'd property.

Comment: got your code working in a plunker.. http://plnkr.co/edit/4Dkgca3k7Hzms27N6kmf?p=preview where do you see `this.date` being changed to `DatePickerComponent `? I checked if it is intsanceof Date and that returns true.

Comment: awesome, thanks!  At the start of ngAfterViewInit() it's reporting as a DatePickerComponent (according to chrome)

Comment: can you fork the plunker and add a log statement where you say the type is `DatePickerComponent`?

Comment: I was just looking at that now but actually where the console.log line is already in ngAfterViewInit shows as a DatePickerComponent in chrome but plunker is not showing that  way :(

Comment: hmmm might there be some other code that is setting `this.date`? or maybe you are logging `this` instead ?

Comment: Is it possible for something else to assign this.date to the wrong class? I thought typescript was strongly typed preventing that from happening. I'm sure I'm not logging 'this' instead of 'this.date' (if I log 'this' it shows date as an object member of type DatePicker Component)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143724/discussion-between-ahmed-musallam-and-ryan0270).

Comment: @AhmedMusallam, I've posted a repo at github.com/ryan0270/…

Comment: Please update your question with all we talked about so that other people can benefit, Otherwise you can delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a look at the [github repo](https://github.com/ryan0270/typechangetest), the issue is this:

daterangepicker.component.ts
line 12 `<qnet-datepicker #startDate [date]="startDate" (dateChange)="updateStart(startDate.date, startTime.value)"></qnet-datepicker>`

the `input` `[date]` is taking a reference to the component itself via template reference variable `#startDate`

removing that fixes the issue.